# Is Visual Studio Code for Raspberry Pi working for every one else?

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

Yesterday, 7/22/2021 VSCode was working fine for me in the morning as it had in the last several months.  While making changes to a program in the editor, I just went to compile and run the program and got a screen full of error messages:

pi@raspberrypi:~/Python $  /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 37243 -- "/home/pi/Python/print("Hello world").py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/pi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.7.1053846006/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/**main**.py", line 45, in 
cli.main()

This is only a partial list but they all had to do with Python, not my program.

I went to my other Raspberry Pi and it also started doing the same thing where it was working fine earlier. I had made no changes there.

So I wrote a HelloWorld single line program, named and saved it and when it ran (both machines) the same compiler messages came up.

Then I went out and bought a new SD card, imaged it on my Windows10 PC, and installed it in my Pi. So far so good but then I installed VSCode, ran their demo HelloWorld program and came up with the same error messages, in fact the exact ones copied above.

I heard on the news that the Internet had major shutdowns around the time yesterday when this problem showed up. That might have something to do with it except that I had re-created my Pi OS today and the problem is still there like I said above.

Searching the Internet for this problem yielded no results. So has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, problem resolved by moving files to another folder. Maybe the Json Config? I can't explain how the problem showed up in the new installation though.